# Can't print on windows shared printer

Tags: windows, printing, samba, hp

server: windows 7 professional
client: ubuntu 16.04
printer: hp color laserjet 1600
The file and printer sharing on the server is on.
I can browse through ubuntu, shared files from the windows machine, I can write there, too.
Also, I can find the printer and install it.
The print command shows completed.
But on the server, the print job shows for a second into print queue then immediately disappears and prints nothing.

This happend after upgrading ubuntu

Comment: Have you installed the printer driver in Ubuntu since upgrading?  Also, this says you "upgraded" but it would be helpful to know which version of Ubuntu this is referring to.  Is it now 16.04 after the upgrade?  If so, which was the last version that worked?  In any case, it is a good thing you have a backup so you can go back to the configuration that works before trying again.

Comment: this wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu sets out what they think is needed; any help?

Comment: Icon name: computer-laptop, Chassis: laptop, Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, Kernel: Linux 4.10.0-35-generic,  Architecture: x86-64.